# Link Button inside Repeater detail section

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have link buttons inside the deatail section of a repeater control.On Edit,the asp.net textboxes will become enabled with change back colour.On Save the values will be saved to the database.To avoid post back i am forced to change server side code to javascript function.How can i write function to do the same action in java script on click of linkbutton.For Update link button ->Is it possible to do the same in Javascript function.

Thanks in advance.

```
         <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" CommandName="edit" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LicenseID") %>' CausesValidation="False" onClientClick="JSFunction();return false">Edit</asp:LinkButton>

         <asp:LinkButton Visible="true" ID="LinkButton5" runat="server" CommandName="update"    CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval    (Container.DataItem, "LicenseID") %>'   CausesValidation="False" onClientClick="MyJSFunction();return  false" >Update</asp:LinkButton>

 If e.CommandName = "edit" Then

      DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("TextBox2"), TextBox).Enabled = True
      DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("Textbox2"), TextBox).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.NotSet
      DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("Textbox2"), TextBox).BackColor = Drawing.Color.White
  end if 

 If e.CommandName = "update" Then

            Dim bookName As String = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("Textbox2"), TextBox).Text

            Dim author As String = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("TextBox3"), TextBox).Text

            Dim pub As String = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("TextBox4"), TextBox).Text

            Dim price As String = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("TextBox5"), TextBox).Text

            Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter("Update abc set License= @License, StartDate=@StartDate,Renewal=@Renewal,VendorPONo=@VendorPONo where LicenseID = @LicenseID", con)

            adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LicenseName", bookName)

            adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", author)

            adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Renewal", pub)

            adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VendorPONo", price)

            adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LicenseID", e.CommandArgument)

            Dim ds As New DataSet()

            adp.Fill(ds)

            BindRepeater()

        End If
```

EDIT

When i try for enabling the textbox as below, 'TextBox4' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level error is showing

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
      function MyJSFunction() {

          var textBox = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox4.ClientID %>");
          textBox.enabled = true;
            textBox.focus();
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer for avoidng the postback through Javascript function.

Below link helped me to solve that.Thanks for all the support.

http://forums.asp.net/p/1949196/5559671.aspx?p=True&t=635199146113886958&pagenum=1

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, what you are looking for is OnClientClick? You can call a javascript function from the OnClientClick event of your Linkbutton control which is client side.

```
<asp:LinkButton Visible="false" ID="lnkUpdate" runat="server" 
CommandName="update"
CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LicenseID") %>' 
CausesValidation="False" OnClientScript='MyJSFunction();return false'>Update</asp:LinkButton>
```

Take a look at this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.onclientclick.aspx

I edited the aswer with the 'return false'. Thanks to adcd shsu

Comment: sorry...can i do the same (Update)in java script function ie as you write MyJSFunction()

Comment: <asp:LinkButton Visible="true" ID="LinkButton5" runat="server" 
CommandName="update"
CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LicenseID") %>' 
CausesValidation="False" onClientClick="MyJSSFunction();return false" >Update</asp:LinkButton>

Comment: What i was looking is the "javascript function" for making the text box inside the repeater enable. (onclick of link button)